# SSL Certificate for Sophos and Portforward to website

Tags: ssl, firewall, web-server, https

If I buy a SSL Certificate for my website and install it to Sophos firewall. Will it be valid if the 443 port is forwarded to inside host (192.168.1.100:443)? Or should it be installed directly to the webserver?

Answer (score 0):

The client side TLS validation (simplified) works as following. A client connects to a server, let say example.com, gets the server certificate and checks, than name inside the certificate matches to example.com. If you install SSL certificate on the server, then your firewall should to SSL termination and forward the traffic to your server without TLS.

If you going to use port forwarding, then a simpler option is to install certificate on the inside host.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on the configuration of the device.

If your firewall is acting as a reverse proxy, or provides web application firewall functionality, or SSL inspection you will need to have the certificate installed on the firewall. These are what make up the bulk of TLS termination at an outside device. That could be a local firewall, a web service like CloudFlare, etc.

If the firewall is strictly doing port forwarding to an internal server the certificate needs to exist on the internal server, and not on the firewall. This is simpler, but a significantly less secure option.